# скрипт выдает ошибки при переходе на другую цену

Tags: c#, unity3d

у меня кликер и я добавил отдельную сцену по кнопке, в другом скрипте сделал штуку чтобы при нажатии переходил. Но скрипт конфликтует и говорит что не куда обновлять

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class clicker : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] int money;
    public Text moneyText;
    public bool isMulti;

    private void Start()
    {
        money = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("money");
        isMulti = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("isMulti") == 1 ? true : false;
    }
    
    public void ButtonClick()
    {
        if (isMulti)
            money += 2;
        else
            money++;
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("money", money);
    }   
    
    public void Magazinilishop()
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene(1);
    }
    
    public void Gotomainmanu()
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene(0);
    }
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        moneyText.text = money.ToString();
    }
    public void Buyxdva()
    {
        if (money >= 999 && isMulti == false)
        {
            money -= 999;
            isMulti = true;
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("money", money);
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("isMulti", isMulti ? 1 : 0);
        }
    }
}`
```

Ошибка

```
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
clicker.Start () (at Assets/scriptss/clicker.cs:40)
```

Comment: Не вижу причин в коде для возникновения указанного исключения. На какой строке возникает? Только не говорите, что на сороковой.

Comment: Если выскакивает ошибка `NullReferenceException` это значит, что в строке где происходит эта ошибка одно из значений равно `null`. Пройдись дебагом по коду и проверь какие значения у тебя `null` который будут использоваться.

Comment: aepot
    void Update()
    {
        moneyText.text = money.ToString();
    }
отвечает за обновление монет в тексте их количества

Answer (score 0):

Иcпользуйте этот метод:

```
[SerializeField] private string nextScene = "Имя загружаемой сцены";

SceneManager.LoadScene("Имя загружаемой сцены");
```

И да,  ваша сцена должна быть в Build Settings

[image: BuildSettings]